# List of preferred namespace prefixes?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, prefix, linked-data, opendata

Are there any lists of preferred namespace abbreviations used in XML and Linked Data? [vann:preferredNamespacePrefix](http://vocab.org/vann/preferredNamespacePrefix.html) describes

> preferred namespace prefix to use when using terms from this vocabulary in an XML document,

but I have a hard time finding a comprehensive list. There are some stats under

- http://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/stats/

but I was hoping for a something more complete.

Note: I already downloaded http://prefix.cc, but there are cases like [dbpedia](http://prefix.cc/dbpedia), where a single prefix is shared by multiple namespaces. I would like to have a 1:1 mapping, e.g. in case of dbpedia, I'd rather have them separated, like on dbpedia itself, e.g. [Berlin](http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin), where `dbpedia`, `dbpprop` and `dbpedia-owl` are all different.

[answers.semanticweb.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20160525052809/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/386/where-to-find-the-most-common-rdfxml-namespace-prefixesbase-urls-as-a-snippet) does not really have a an answer.

Comment: Note that, in general, prefixes don't matter. You could use `ns1`, `ns2`, etc., and it would have the same effect as using `pfx1`, `pfx2`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I know. We have a user facing component, and things like 'rdf:type' and 'owl:sameAs' are kind of familiar now, so we thought we try to use the most common abbreviations.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most useful resource for now might be:

- http://prefix.cc/popular/all.rdf (a bit more machine readable [here](https://gist.github.com/miku/0f755aa4c13fd8badac7))